# Chef how to add,enable and install in one code block

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

i have this procedure on installing specific version of php in centos

```
yum install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum install php
```

how to include all this procedure in one code block in Chef? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be achieved in various ways:

1. store the command(s) in a shell script and execute it with the [`execute`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html), [`bash`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html) or [`script`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_script.html) resources
2. converting your commands to "pure" chef resources, such as [`package`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html) [`yum_package`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_yum_package.html), [`yum_repository`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_yum_repository.html) resources